# Android Media Volume locked after I kill

Tags: android, volume, android-audiomanager, locked

I have a huge bug in my app. After I finish the app the volume is muted and it's locked.

Even when I quit and restart the app the volume is still locked at mute. The only way to restore the volume is to restart the phone. Please help! The app is a 2 `webviews` and one of the `webviews` is a `video stream`.

The log says this every time I push the volume button:

```
02-12 11:45:12.939: V/AudioHardwareMSM76XXA(115): AudioHardware::getParameters()
Fm-radio=

02-12 11:37:29.639: D/LKW(198): mShowing= false mNeedToReshowWhenReenabled= false
mUpdateMonitor.isDeviceProvisioned()= true
```

My audio manager methods:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
    lock.release();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
    lock.acquire();

}
**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that something was causing a task to not be killed. It was bugging the phones volume and the app was running in the background and consuming RAM and battery. I solved it by killing the all the tasks myself.

Add KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES to the manifest.
Then kill the tasks.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    final ActivityManager amm = (ActivityManager)Class.this.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    amm.restartPackage("com.liyicky.dbzhd");
    amm.killBackgroundProcesses("com.liyicky.dbzhd");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the same code you are using on your onPause to your onDestroy method, it should help even if the app crashed :
**Note it is not gurenteed to get called, but in most cases it does**

```
protected void onDestroy(){
      super.onDestroy();
       am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
       am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I've tried that and I've tried almost 100 different variations of that. haha